# How do you setup your repo for IAC?

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code

When setting up your Terraform repo, how would you setup your infrastructure as code repo?  What if you work in an environment where separation of duties is still dominant?

Would you make repos for multiple services ?

for example
a repo for account
then in there you have a network repo, iam repo, services repo, security repo, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Division of code between repositories is very subjective. It's whatever is easiest for you to manage.

Some facts about Terraform which may make the decision easier:

- you select a single directory when running Terraform. This means you have to run Terraform multiple times if you store code across multiple directories, or do some kind of preprocessing to flatten the directories (not pleasant).
- [Terraform modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html) exist. They can help you encapsulate related Terraform resources into a reusable component.
- There is a set of `terraform state` subcommands, which allow you to refactor (split or combine) state files for Terraform-managed resources at a later date. So, if you choose the wrong layout first time, it is reversible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a separate repo for multiple services. However, you can use modules for your services.

You can structure your modules like the below structure.

```
- modules --> global --> iam 
                     --> route53
          --> network --> vpc
                      --> vpc-peering 
          --> compute --> ec2 
                      --> ecs --> services --> webapp1
                                           --> webapp2
```